# Vajra killing Hanuman

Tags: ramayana, hanuman

I have a confusion over Hanuman being killed by Vajra of Indra, after Hanuman eating the sun. I have read several versions, and in most of these, it was mentioned that Hanuman became unconscious, and was not killed, as shown in the Mahabali Hanuman TV serial.

Let us analyze it further.

Hanuman was an avatar of Lord Shiva, who cannot be killed by anyone in the universe. Hanuman also ate up the entire sun, which is more energetic than the Vajra. So, how Hanuman lost his life on the Vajra hitting him?

Comment: You see hanuman was not amar before being hit by vajra. Also vajra is/was a very powerful weapon made from the corpse of sage dadhichi. After Vayu Deva took all the air of universe in all the gods had to give back the life of Hanuman and make him Ajar and Amar to serve the purpose he took birth for.

Comment: Yes, Hanuman was not amar before being hit by vajra. Analyse the situation with logical considerations. Hanuman ate up the sun, which is more powerful than Vajra; he also captured Kaal and neutarlized agni. Vajra is powerful no doubt; but what about Ravaana and Indrajeet, who could counter Vajra. So, it seems not true that Hanuman was killed by Vajra; it might have rendered him unconsious, as I have read in many versions.

Comment: "Hanuman was an avatar of Lord Shiva". This not per definition a fact. There are conflicting verses about this.

Answer (score 1):

Mythological stories are like *Fairy tales*. The objective of these stories , is to inculcate some moral principles in the mind of the reader. You cannot apply strictly *scientific methods* to analyze them .**The moral priciples that they teach may be questioned**.
 Recently ,there is going on a **TV Serial** , in *Colours channel* in Indian TV---which shows the life and activities of **Hanuman** .
 The problem you are referring to , has been shown and discussed in detail there.You may watch that serial .
 Since there is no public criticism of the events shown in this serial ,it may be assumed the story is consistent with the description of *Puranas* .
 While bringing out the *new reprints of the original Puranas in Sanskrit* or their *translated version in local languages* ,the writers take the liberty of *modifying their contents, to suit to the requirement of the times*.

Comment: But, Hanuman being killed by Vajra, that too, after defeating Angi, Varun, Kaal, before eating the Sun, is very inconsistent.